# Javascript video player not loading randomly selected video

Tags: javascript

I'm coding my first JavaScript video player. It has a main window and three side windows that are to be populated with random videos. When a person clicks on a side video it will move to the main window and a randomly selected video will replace its spot in the side window.

I have got it working so that the top side video moves to the main window upon selection. I plan to replicate this code with the other videos once I have it figured out. The problem I'm having is in replacing the selected side video window with a random video selected from a video cache.

I've tried numerous variations of the following code.

JavaScript

```
    // Change main video to selection 
    var video = document.getElementById('one');
    video.src = "videos/video-2.mp4";   


    //VideoCache Array
    var videoCache = ["video-1.mp4", "video-2.mp4", "video-3.mp4",  "video-4.mp4", "video-5.mp4", "video-6.mp4", "video-7.mp4", "video-8.mp4",  "video-9.mp4", "video-10.mp4"];

    //Select Random Video   
    selectVideo = videoCache[Math.floor(Math.random() * videoCache.length) *1]; 


    //Add selected video to second video slot   
    var video2 = document.getElementById('two');
    video2.src = "selectVideo"; 

});
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Oakland Commune</title>
    <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "style.css" />    
  </head>
  <body>

  <p id="test">Test Me!<p>

  <div id = "wrapper">

     <div id ="first" class="video-wrappers"> 
        <video id="one" width="400" controls>
            <source src="videos/video-1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
        </video>
     </div>

      <div id ="second" class="video-wrappers">
         <video id="two" width="400" controls>
            <source src=" type="video/mp4">
            Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
        </video>
      </div>

      <div id ="third" class="video-wrappers">
           <video id="three" width="400" controls>
            <source src="videos/video-3.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
        </video>
          </div>
  <div id ="fourth" class="video-wrappers">
           <video id="four" width="400" controls>
            <source src="videos/video-4.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
        </video>
      </div>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

The random video that is to replace the selected video doesn't load.

Comment: Open the F12 developer tools and go to the console tab.  Do you see any errors as the page loads and the script code runs?

Comment: Yeah, this: Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND. So i guess the problem is the path to the video?

Comment: What is this `<source src=" type="video/mp4">` ?

Comment: So that's a mistake. But even if I replace that line with what it's supposed to be: ```<source src="videos/video-2.mp4" type="video/mp4">```
it still fails to load the new video that is randomly selected.

Comment: Is the error still :ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND? Are you sure videos/video-2.mp4 exists as a sub-folder and file of the location where your HTML page is?

Comment: HI Dave. Thanks for getting back. Yes, it's still showing the same error. The path to the video files is dialed-in and works for all the videos other than when trying to select a random one.